# WP audio video player with previous next options

Tags: plugins

I need the audio video player plugin with the following controls:
previous, next, play, stop options. It needs to play continuously like windows media player.

I searched over, but couldn't find the exact one. Is there any possibility for this. Please do the needful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this plugins:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-video-player/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/player/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/hdw-player-video-player-video-gallery/